# how to unblockUI relative when the page finished loading or a "content" finished loading

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#storefront').click(function() {
        $(".centerdiv").load("storefront_a.php");
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } }); 

        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    }); 
});
```

I got this code from [Malsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) . It worked on any browsers except IE. The script simply generate a full screen "Please Wait" with interval of 2 seconds before it disappear.

"What I want is to only remove the "Please Wait" screen whenever a content or the page finshed loading. is it possible. Thanks for Helping me! I will appreciate every answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the optional callback function of [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#storefront').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff'
        } }); 
        $(".centerdiv").load("storefront_a.php", function() {
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: waw. very fast answers . I thought load can only handle one parameter. thanks BTW!